Upgrading to pgadmin 4.8 is resulting in slow queries
On my Windows 10 machine, I'm running Postgres 10.5
I had previously been running pgadmin 4.3 and it worked well.
I just upgraded to pgadmin 4.8, which now runs in its own app (versus the browser), but the most basic query against my localdb is taking over 1 second.
For example, the query
select id from mytable where id =1; (this table only has 200 rows) is taking 1.2 seconds!
It should take milliseconds.
Is there a setting I'm missing or why would these most basic queries be performing like this?
I am now looking to install an older version to see if that helps.
UPDATE:
FYI, I just tried version 7.8, and had the same slow queries.
But when I installed version 6.21, it worked as expected..queries taking milliseconds.
Seems like version 7.8 and newer introduces some serious performance issues...at least that's what I'm seeing.
